# Limit solution domain in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

How should you write the `Solve` command or another to give me solutions to this equation for example

1. integers
2. rationals

Here are the equations:

```
Solve[
  x + y + z == 100 && 
  x == 7*p && 
  y == 17*q && 
  z == 27*r,
  {x, y, z}
]
```

Comment: @MarcoB  ,thaks, I wrote it right, I'm sure I will take it

Comment: Good, just checking. I’ve taken the liberty to fix it in your question then.

Comment: Shouldn't for this kind of condition, the domain should be more restrictive since for `Integers`, given any `p` you can find `q` and `r` which would satisfy the condition and for `Rationals`, given any `p` and `q` you can find an `r` that will satisfy the condition. But only for more restrictive domains which are not closed under subtraction like `PositiveIntegers`, `NonNegativeIntegers`, `PositiveRationals`, `NonNegativeRationals` you can find interesting solutions.

Comment: @user13892 I think you are right about the restricted domain part. I was trying to find out why solve gave wrong result when telling it `r,p,q` are integers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p,q,r$ integers using `Solve` it actually did not work. I got result from Solve which is not valid, I do not know if this is a bug or it is by design

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, p, q, r];
eq1 = x + y + z == 100;
eq2 = x == 7*p;
eq3 = y == 17*q;
eq4 = z == 27*r;
const = Element[{p, q, r}, Integers];
sol = {x, y, z} /. 
   First@Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, const}, {x, y, z}] // Normal

(* {7 p, 17 q, 100 - 7 p - 17 q} *)
```

So `r` is implicit in the above. Can be found from the relation `z == 27*r` which means `r = z/27`. But when I run the above over few integer values of `p,q`, it shows `r` is not integer:

```
sol0 = Flatten[
  Table[Evaluate[
    Flatten@{sol, sol[[1]] + sol[[2]] + sol[[3]], p, q, sol[[3]]/27, 
      7*p, 17*q}], {p, 1, 3}, {q, 1, 3}], 1]

Grid[PrependTo[sol0, {"x", "y", "z", "x+y+z", "p", "q", "r", "x=7*p", "y=17*q"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

However, it "works"  if constraint is as mentioned in comments above, more restrictive than `Integers`. For example

```
const = Element[{p, q, r}, PositiveIntegers];
sol = {x, y, z} /. 
   First@Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, const}, {x, y, z}] // Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and for `PositiveRationals`

```
const = Element[{p, q, r}, PositiveRationals];
sol = {x, y, z} /. 
   First@Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, const}, {x, y, z}] // Normal

(* {7 p, 17 q, 100 - 7 p - 17 q} *)
 sol0 = Flatten[
  Table[Evaluate[
    Flatten@{sol, sol[[1]] + sol[[2]] + sol[[3]], p, q, sol[[3]]/27, 
      7*p, 17*q, sol[[3]]}], {p, 1, 4}, {q, 1, 4}], 1]
Grid[PrependTo[
  sol0, {"x", "y", "z", "x+y+z", "p", "q", "r", "x=7*p", "y=17*q", 
   "27*r"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

And now it is correct, `r` is rational, but that is OK.

So I think `Solve` did not work in first case above, because `r,p,q` domain was set as `Integers`. May be this is by design. I do not know now.

Comment: @Nasser_Thank you for your answer and the time invested in it. I have enough points.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for integer `p,q,r`, you should just use `FrobeniusSolve[]` instead:

```
FrobeniusSolve[{7, 17, 27}, 100]
   {{7, 3, 0}, {8, 1, 1}}
```

Check:

```
%.{7, 17, 27}
   {100, 100}
```